# How to get the objects with array of object Id in Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have an array of `objectIds = ["LlbAXkqOL4", "v7lSgUunbR"]`

If I have only one object id, then I can use,

`query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("A2332xsdas2")`
Since I have many objectIds, I am following this code:

```
    let userQuery = PFUser.query()
    userQuery?.whereKey("username", equalTo: self.user!.username!)
    userQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (object, error) -> Void in
        if object != nil
        {
            for messageObject in object! {
                self.importedArray = ((messageObject as! PFObject)["AllEventsId"] as? [String]!)!
                println("importedArray = \(self.importedArray)")
            }
        }
    }


    var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Events")
    query.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: self.importedArray)
    query.whereKey("EventSTDTime", greaterThan: zDate)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (object, error) -> Void in
        if object != nil
        {
            println(objects)
        }
     }
```

Here is the screenshot: [image: screenshot]

But this method is not working as it fetched all the id under the class `Events`

Comment: I didnt get what problem you are facing. What do you mean by "is not working as it fetched all the id under the class Events". Please give more details.

Comment: In `Events` class, if I have 10 rows, it is fetching all the 10 rows, I want only the rows that have the `objectId` am mentioning in the array: `objectIds`

Comment: Its working for me. does this importedArray has the right data?

Comment: yes, I could get the `importedArray` in console and it is good.

Comment: show me what you trying

Comment: how? can u come to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89318/discussion-between-aaa-and-adolfosrs).

Comment: You are printing "objects" in this case you should println(object). This will print all the objects with the ids on the arry.

Comment: tried that too... not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure why your request is returning the whole class info. But the point here is that parse background methods run assynchronously and you cant iterate over them.

The solution that might work for you is the following:

```
var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Events")
    query.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: objectIds)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
                println(objects)
    })
```

Comment: you sure those ids are stored in your database? could you please edit your question with a sreenshot of your parse table?